# Compile time Bimap static_assert failure

Tags: c++, c++17, compile-time

I am trying to have a simple compile time Bimap with the use of `constexpr` and `std::array`.

This seems to work fine with the first example. 
However with the second example I have the following static error:

> error: static_assert failed "3 == 3.3"
>           static_assert(meta_dict.find_key_of_value(3) == 3.3, "3 == 3.3");    // fails

Here the code available on [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ugXGwvqvKYttoKeU). Should compile (except the above error) with `Clang>=5.0.0` and `GCC>=8.0.0`.

```
#include <utility>
#include <array>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

template<class Key, class Value, std::size_t N>
struct MetaBimap {
    using Item = std::pair<Key, Value>;

    constexpr MetaBimap(const std::array<Item, N>& d)
        : dictionnary{d}
        {}

    constexpr Value find_value_of_key(const Key& key, int range = N) const
    {
        if (range == 0)
            throw std::out_of_range("Cannot find key");
        return (dictionnary[range - 1].first == key) 
            ? dictionnary[range - 1].second
            : find_value_of_key(key, range - 1);
    }

    constexpr Key find_key_of_value(const Value& value, int range = N) const
    {
        if (range == 0)
            throw std::out_of_range("Cannot find value");
        return (dictionnary[range - 1].second == value) 
            ? dictionnary[range - 1].first
            : find_key_of_value(value, range - 1);
    }

    std::array<Item, N> dictionnary;
};


int main() 
{   
    // first example
    {
        using namespace std::string_view_literals;
        constexpr std::array<std::pair<std::string_view, int>, 3> meta_array {{
            { "one"sv, 1 },
            { "two"sv, 2 },
            { "three"sv, 3 }
        }};
        constexpr MetaBimap<std::string_view, int, 3> meta_dict = meta_array;

        // OK on wandbox with Clang>=5.0.0 and GCC>=8.0.0 (though not working on my computer with Clang=5.0.0)
        static_assert(meta_dict.find_value_of_key("one"sv) == 1, "one == 1");       
        static_assert(meta_dict.find_key_of_value(3) == "three"sv, "3 == three"); 
    }

    // second example
    {
        constexpr std::array<std::pair<float, int>, 3> meta_array {{
            { 1.1, 1 },
            { 2.2, 2 },
            { 3.3, 3 }
        }};
        constexpr MetaBimap<float, int, 3> meta_dict = meta_array;

        static_assert(meta_dict.find_value_of_key(1.1) == 1, "1.1 == 1");       // OK
        std::cout << meta_dict.find_key_of_value(3) << std::endl;
        // static_assert(meta_dict.find_key_of_value(3) == 3.3, "3 == 3.3");    // fails
    }
}
```

Why is there a static failure here and how to fix it ? 
Also as bonus, any way to simplify the construction of the bimap ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem can be reduced to this:

```
constexpr float a = 3.3;
static_assert (a == 3.3f, "float 3.3 is different from literal compiled 3.3f"); // ok
static_assert (a == 3.3, "float 3.3 is different from literal compiled 3.3"); //this fails
```

the literal 3.3 written in code is treated by compiler as a double, and when comparing a float with a double, having them different precisions, it can happens (almost always) they don't match

with `3.3f` you are telling the compiler that the literal written in code should be treated as `float`, while not specifying any suffix will default to `double`

Have a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal)

Comment: This demonstrates that using floating-point numbers a keys is at best dangerous.

Comment: for sure @Walter!